# Encrypted Querystring in URL getting changed to lowercase in Outlook

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, url, encryption

I am providing a CANCEL button in a registration email, so that the user can click the link and cancel their registration.

This works fine except Outlook is converting links to lowercase.
So when the user clicks the link, I can't decrypt the URL because the encrypted querystring is now all lowercase and longer valid.

What can I do prevent Outlook from converting links to lowercase, or how can I provide a Link that is URL encrypted and case insensitive?

**Summary**:

> domain.com/cancel?qs=**YLway3mDMmWMw**

is getting changed to:

> domain.com/cancel?qs=**ylway3mdmmwmw**

which breaks the ability to decrypt the querystring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If outlook is sabotaging your links, then you need to make your links case indifferent. If you absolutely must keep upper and lowercase in your links for decryption, use a marker character:

1. Generate encrypted string.
2. Before each upper case character, insert marker character (pick a valid character your encryption scheme does not use).
3. Insert your new string into the link.
4. To decrypt, remove any marker characters as you parse the string and make uppercase/lowercase as appropriate.

Here is a pair of helper methods if you find it easier reading code:

```
            private static string EncodeCasingIndifference(string originalText, char markerChar)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach(char c in originalText)
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(c))
                sb.Append(markerChar);

            sb.Append(c);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private static string DecodeCasingIndifference(string encryptedText, char markerChar)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        bool nextCharIsUpper = false;

        foreach(char c in encryptedText)
        {
            if(c == markerChar)
            {
                nextCharIsUpper = true;
                continue;
            }

            if(nextCharIsUpper)
                sb.Append(char.ToUpperInvariant(c));
            else
                sb.Append(char.ToLowerInvariant(c));

            nextCharIsUpper = c == markerChar;
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Passing your original link payload into the "enode" method with a dash ('-') as the marker character returns: `-Y-Lway3m-D-Mm-W-Mw`

Passing `-y-lway3m-d-mn-w-mw` into the "decode" method with a dash ('-') as the marker character returns your original link payload

Comment: I ended up writing a new encryption method that was case indifferent. However, I'm marking this as an answer, because it certainly is way around the problem.